# VBA - If Loop for two sets of Data

Tags: vba, excel

So I have two columns of data and I want to add a date next to data that has two sets of values. So if A3 = Trucks and B3  = 2008 appear in the two columns I want C3 to have a date value of 11/1/2016. If these values A3 = Trucks and B3 = 2008 appear anywhere else in the data I want the date value to increase by 1 to 11/2/2016 and have that run until the data is fully queried.

Comment: Sounds good - let us know if you run into any specific problems with that. Likely you can do this more easily using a worksheet formula like `COUNTIFS()`  If you want to use VBA then typically people here like to see some code you've already tried, along with a description of what's not working (error messages etc)

Comment: to understand your problem, A3 = Trucks, B3 = 2008, C3 = 11/1/2016. if A10 = Trucks, B10 = 2008, you want C10 = C3 +1 i.e. 11/2/2016. Right?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i understand from your question

```
if A3 = Trucks, B3 = 2008, C3 = 11/1/2016. then
if A10 = Trucks, B10 = 2008, then C10 = C3 +1 i.e. 11/2/2016
```

if my understanding is right, the below formula should work. Here is a [google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pWTXPecjO5jOh9oPurZk1P0bLJIiYvKOl9AI_ncZNEM/edit?usp=sharing).

```
IF(MAX(--($A$1:A8=A9)*--($B$1:B8=B9)*ROW($A$1:A8))>0,OFFSET($C$1,MAX(--($A$1:A8=A9)*--($B$1:B8=B9)*ROW($A$1:A8))-1,0)+1,"New Date")
```

Please note the formula is an array formula i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing in cell. Also I have added an if clause, in case the item is appearing for the first time in the list, it will show "New Date".